# scrollIntoView only works when in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Whenever I use scrollIntoView, I need to wrap it under a setTimeout function, if I don't, scrollIntoView doesn't work.

Basically,
For some reason this code **works**:

```
setTimeout(function () {
      if(el != null) {
        el.scrollIntoView({
          behavior: "smooth",
          block: "start",
      });
      }
}, 100);
```

But this one **doesn't**:

```
if(el != null) {
      el.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "start",
      });
}
```

I really want to understand why, as it seems like a bad solution to my problem.
This code is implemented in my header component, so onClick it scrolls into a specific section of the page. The header component and the rest of page are in separate components, I feel like this has something to do with that.

**Edit 1:**
I couldn't get it to work with Stackblitz, preview isn't loading. But the code is called by:

```
<ul *ngFor="let pill of pills" class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item" [ngSwitch]="activePage"><a href="#" (click)="clickedPill(pill)" [ngClass]="{active: this.activePage == pill.pillName}" class="nav-link" aria-current="page"><i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i><u>{{pill.pillName}}</u></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is clickedPill() in it's entirety:

```
pills = [
    {"pillName": "Sobre Mim", "pillId": "about"},
    {"pillName": "Projetos", "pillId": "projects"},
    {"pillName": "Stacks", "pillId": "stacks"},
    {"pillName": "Formação", "pillId": "scholarity"}
  ];
  activePage: string = "Sobre Mim";

  clickedPill(pill: any){
    this.activePage = pill.pillName;
    console.log(`scrolling to ${pill.pillId}`);
    let el = document.getElementById(pill.pillId);
    console.log(document.getElementById(pill.pillId))
    // Provavel função assincrona, transformar depois e ver o resultado
    setTimeout(function () {
      if(el != null) {
        el.scrollIntoView({
          behavior: "smooth",
          block: "start",
      });
      }
 }, 100);
```

Comment: what is calling this code? perhaps there is a timing issue. More context will help. If you can, make a minimal reproducible stackblitz

Comment: @Tanner I couldn't get Stackblitz to work, but I added the HTML that calls the parent function, and the entire parent function.

Comment: It might be the href="#" on your anchor interfering with the scroll.

Comment: @Tanner you got it, it was absolutely the href="#", switched it with href="javascript:void(0)" and it worked. I'm now aware I shouldn't even be using <a> tag for a function, but I still wanted to understand the setTimeout solution. Thanks a lot.